# How Gamma Encoding increases the shadow detail?

Tags: image, gamma

[image]

Linear Encoding

[image]

Gamma Encoding

As you can see from the top image, Linear Encoding incurs color banding.

On the other hand, Gamma Encoding(the bottom image) shows the better quality in the shadow detail.

As far as I know, Monitor cancels out Gamma Encoding by applying Gamma Decoding on the gamma corrected image.

So, I thought that the results of applying Linear Decoding on linear image and applying Gamma Decoding on gamma corrected image would be same.


How Gamma Encoding increases the shadow detail?